# Nativescript Radlistview position and z-index of selected item checkmark icon

Tags: ios, nativescript, radlistview

Is it possible to change the position of the checkbox/checkmark of the selected item?

In the grid template of the radlistview the checkmark icon is on left side of each item and vertically centered. Also If each cell is filled with an image, the checkmark is no longer visible.

Is there anyway to change its position and also its z-index?

Here is the screenshot of how the icons are placed:

[image]

Here is the Radlistview XML:

```
<lv:RadListView row="1" items="{{ items }}" selectionBehavior="Press" multipleSelection="true" itemSelected="itemSelected" itemDeselected="itemDeselected" >
  <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
    <lv:ListViewGridLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" ios:itemWidth="125" ios:itemHeight="125" spanCount="3"/>
  </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
  <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    <GridLayout rows="*">
      <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
        <AbsoluteLayout margin="1" borderBottomWidth="2" borderBottomColor="#189DD3">
          <Image width="135" height="135" src="{{ itemSrc }}" itemIndex="{{ itemIndex }}" stretch="aspectFill" opacity="0.7"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
      </GridLayout>
    </GridLayout>
  </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot to make it easier to understand?

Comment: @Manoj added the screenshot of how the icons are placed inside each cell (decreased my image opacity so that icons are visible). I'd like to position them on the lower-left or right and increase their z-index.

Comment: Can you share your html for listview row template?

Comment: Looks like a problem with layout only

Comment: @NarendraMongiya Included the XML

Comment: in itemTemplate , where is the code for checkbox? you are using GridLayout with one row only and that will overlap whatever items you have

Comment: I am not using the thirparty plugin "checkbox". The checkmark icon you see in the photo is the default checkmark of the radlistview

Comment: @JDrake Can you please confirm which option enables you access to checkbox, with given code I'm unable to see checkbox in the list items. It selects item only by applying a different background color.

Comment: @Manoj perhaps you misunderstood it with android. It's radlistview on ios and by default it has that checkmark when selection or multiple selection is enabled. There is no extra code for the checkmark necessary, by default it has that checkmark you see in the screenshot. What I want to know is: how can I change its position and z-index.

Comment: I'm able to see the issue and unfortunately these components are not open source yet, so I think we have to wait to hear back from the team in feedback repo.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to customise the `z-Index` or alignment of default checkbox, use the `nativescript-checkbox` plugin and maintain selection state within your data item. By doing so you can have similar look and feel for both iOS & Android.

Source: https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/887